# React Native on iOS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building a React Native app. On iOS after implementing camera features, the iOS app suddenly decided to crash.

I get the following error:

```
2018-10-29 14:48:26.353 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect')
2018-10-29 14:48:26.356 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManager.Aspect')
2018-10-29 14:48:26.368 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
2018-10-29 14:48:26.379 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

I found several threads about this problem and did all the respective solutions. I did run `react-native link`, I restarted Metro, I cleaned my build folder and here is my `index.js` (I'm also using React Native Firebase, but when I added that, everything still worked...):

```
/** @format */

import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./app/App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import bgMessaging from "./app/services/fcm";

// New task registration
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask("RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage", () => bgMessaging);
// Current main application
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: permissions are handled for using camera in ios ??

Comment: using any library for camera ??

Comment: @tahirmahmood Yeah, I use [react-native-qr-code-scanner](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner) which uses [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera).

Comment: then you have to check that react-native-camera is properly linked in ios project.. are you linking through pods or through old way of linking

Comment: I linked it now manually and that worked :)

Comment: @J.Hesters how did you link it manually?  Can you please give a step by step way of accomplishing it?

Comment: @TimNuwin I can't, I'm sorry. This was months ago and I'm not working wit h RN any more. Check out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking to see the steps for manual linking.